# Want to loop Imacros from line 7 instead of line 1

Tags: imacros

Is it possible to loop imacros from line 7 instead of line one

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
PROXY ADDRESS= ????
SET !LOOP 1
URL GOTO=google.nl/
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.nl/
URL GOTO=https://www.nu.nl/
URL GOTO=https://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

i want to run the first lines only 1 time until the SET !LOOP 1 then i want to start after the line SET !LOOP 1

if its possible then how?

thnx anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it is not possible with imacros

Answer (score 2):

yes is possible just make a csv file and put the value in the first row only then it will take the IP address from the first row and for the next row because it will be blank there will be not changes further.... i hope it will help

and if you want to change the ip after 100 or 200 or 500 loops then put the another ip address on the the particular row and the ip will change as well...

Comment: I dont really know how this works with the csv file.
could u make an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSV file with all of the URL's you wish to go to in a **single column** then place it into the datasource file (not required, but much easier: documents\imacros\datasources).

For the sake of this example I will call your datalist "weburl.csv" obviously, this can be changed to whatever you'd like. You can also use .txt files if you'd prefer but remember you'd have to call it "weburl.txt" instead.

In your weburl.csv file you'd have:

```
google.nl/
https://www.facebook.nl/
https://www.nu.nl/
https://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

And your imacro would look like this. Remember, if you change the datasource file name/extension you'd need to change it next to !SET DATASOURCE

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE weburl.txt 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
PROXY ADDRESS=????
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
```

The only problem I found with this script is that it will keep opening your URLs in a single tab so I took the time to change it around a little so that each URL opens in a new tab, just in case that's how you'd like this script to run. :)

```
TAB T={{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE weburl.txt 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
PROXY ADDRESS=????
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
TAB OPEN
TAB T={{!LOOP}}
```

Comment: Just noticed the date. Damn you search function.

Answer (score 0):

[Nested Loops](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q%3a_How_to_create_nested_loops.3F)
and 
[Macro starting other macro](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q%3a_Can_a_macro_start_another_macro.3F)

Check these links out maybe you can tweak it a bit to your liking. 
If you want yo u can create the same macro script but without everything before the loop and let the 1st macro start the 2nd macro without:

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
PROXY ADDRESS= ????
SET !LOOP 1
```

Then you won't need this part in your second macro script, which then will start from:

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=google.nl/
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.nl/
URL GOTO=https://www.nu.nl/
URL GOTO=https://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

Ofcourse the first script will still have the first options ofcourse.

Imacro's iimPlay: [iimPlay of Imacro](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

im fixed it by using OS's automator to open firefox the diffrent tabs choose proxy and log-in and start the macro

(yes i use a mac)

Answer (score -1):

Same problem.
You want to start from line 7

It always goes to login page.

```
VERSION BUILD=6060703 RECORDER=CR URL
GOTO=http://www.smsurdu.net/index.php TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT
FORM=ID:login ATTR=ID:username CONTENT=03356105927 SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:login ATTR=ID:password
CONTENT=ali6689084 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:login
ATTR=NAME:submit


URL GOTO=http://www.smsurdu.net/u-send-free-sms.php TAG POS=1
TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sendingsms ATTR=ID:phone-no
CONTENT=03356105927 TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:sendingsms
ATTR=ID:sms CONTENT=bloghaider.com TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT
FORM=ID:sendingsms ATTR=NAME:submit
```